# How do I store local javascript results from an ajax call to be shown later?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, arrays

I have an ajax query that returns an array . . I only show the first 20 items in the array right now but i have now added a link for "Show All" after I displayed those first results.

When the user clicks **Show All** i want to display all of the items in the array.(either inline or in a dialog (but that implementation shouldn't matter)

I want to avoid having to go back to the server to get the full list since I already retrieved the full list from the first ajax call . . where is the best way to locally store this array to be accessed later.

Comment: What's wrong with just storing it in a Javascript variable and then accessing that variable later?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Save the array in a variable, or possibly attached as a data element to something on the DOM.  Then, when your "Show All" event fires, read from that array and rebuild your display.

```
<div id="myArrayDisplay">
</div>

<script>
$(function () {
 $.getJSON("backendCode.php", function (jsonData) { // assumes your array arrives as a response from a JSON-based Ajax request to some server code
  $("#myArrayDisplay").data("arrayObj", jsonData);
 });

});
</script>
```

Obviously I'm not showing how you would display the contents of the array in the above code, just how I would store it.

Comment: how do i scope that array variable? At the top of my js file ?

Comment: Honestly, I would probably "scope" it by assigning it to a data key on the DOM element you're using to display it.  I'll update my answer to show more detail.

Comment: Yes, jQuery is cross browser tested and this is a core jQuery function.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easy way you can do is to put the full list data into a hidden input textfield

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the best way, but the simplest is using a global variable.

Define it here:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $.myArray = [];

})
```

And use it like so:

```
function myFunction(){

  alert($.myArray[0]);

}
```

More info about [$(document).ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/).

On the other hand, you could create two separate fields, one with the initial info and one with the rest, making the second one invisible. When the user clicks "Show more" you can show the hidden one.

More information about [.show()](http://api.jquery.com/show/).